# Heterogenous List Slicing

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I want to do a basic plot of price vs. amount of different products. My input data would that look like this:

```
P = np.array((1.75, 250), (1.59, 355), (1.25, 330))
```

Now i can get the prices with `P[:, 0]`. But now I want to add the brand name too, like this:

```
P = ((1.75, 250, "Store 1"), (1.59, 355, "Store 2"), (1.25, 330, "Store 3"))
```

Because I mix strings and numbers here, I can no longer use a `np.array` as I don't want numbers as strings. But now I can no longer do `P[:, 0]` to get the prices (it gives me a `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple`).

So is there an easy way to still access the prices in a heterogeneous list like this? I know I could put them in different lists, but I though this way I might learn something new about Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a struct array; [start here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html)

Comment: So am I assuming correctly that at the cost of explicitly specifying the size and name of each element, you get 'slicing' that is performance-wise more or less equivalent to the np.array and superior to the other two suggestions (which are therefore easier and more flexible)?

Comment: Also: struct arrays seem to only support byte literals (which makes sense), however if I print them, or pass them to Matplotlib as tick labels, the b'' gets printed, too. I know I could use .decode with list comprehension, but this would sort of the purpose of this exercise. So am I stuck with these two options?

Comment: 1: yeah, that's basically it; the other solution will not give you numpy-like speed; although that may be a tolerable thing for plot axes, which typically don't number in the millions. 2: I don't have any experience there, sorry.

Comment: Yes it would be completely tolerable, but I was trying to learn a more elegant way of doing it, which I feel I did.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension:

```
>>> P = ((1.75, 250, "Store 1"), (1.59, 355, "Store 2"), (1.25, 330, "Store 3"))
>>> [product[0] for product in P]
[1.75, 1.59, 1.25]
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) expression?

```
>>> P = ((1.75, 250, "Store 1"), (1.59, 355, "Store 2"), (1.25, 330, "Store 3"))
>>> price = map(lambda x: x[0], P)
>>> price
[1.75, 1.59, 1.25]
```